# Uploading file to server throws file or directory not found exception

Tags: java, file-upload

Below is the code i have used to upload a file to the server. But the code throws a exception directory or file not found..

```
                ResourceBundle rs_mail = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mail");
                String upload_path = rs_mail.getString("upload_path");
                File file = null;
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                // Parse the request to get file items.
                List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                // Process the uploaded file items
                Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
                    File uploadDir = new File(upload_path);
                    if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                        uploadDir.mkdir();
                    }
                  file = new File(upload_path + file.separator + fi.getName());

                    fi.write(file);
                }
```

Can any one point out the reason for the exception..

Contents of the property file

upload_path=../../../upload

Comment: The exception is quite clear: "directory or file not found."  Have you tried debugging your code to determine what file or directory doesn't exist?

Comment: yes exception is caused at this line   fi.write(file);

Comment: Is `upload_path` a regular file instead of a directory? Does `fi` have any slashes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you also create all the parent directories on the path to `upload_path`:

```
if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
   uploadDir.mkdirs();
}
```

Note the use of `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()`. `mkdir()` will fail, if the parent structure does not exist. `mkdirs()` will also try to create the required parent directories.

You should also check for the return value, both methods will return `false` if the directory could not be created.

Comment: Ur answer help me. But the problem the path. I was trying to create a folder within tomcat. Ubuntu was blocking it. I should consider servlet context. Thanks for the help.